# Ethernet Network Card & WiFi Card

Tags: internet

My Ubuntu 12.10 box has two network cards, Ethernet card (`Eth0`) is connected to internal network (`192.168.18.0/24`) without any internet access, Wireless card (`Wlan0`) is connected to intranet (`10.124.64.0, 255.255.252.0`) which has internet access. When I try to access internet, I have to disable Ethernet card (`Eth0`). Is there any way to config ip route from Ubuntu, something like `0.0.0.0  0.0.0.0 Wlan0`, so I can access internet without disable Ethernet 0 card. Thanks for your help.

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use the `route` command to find out what your current routing table looks like. It will probably look somewhat like this:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.18.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.18.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
10.124.64.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 wlan0
...
```

Now you will want to replace the default gateway by a gateway on the `10.124.64/24` net. You can find out its IP by running `route` when eth0 is disabled or unplugged. Assuming it is the `.1`, you would then execute:

```
route del default
route add default gw 10.124.64.1
```

If you want to automate this, you could add these commands to an `up` statement in the appropriate stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces` (see `man interfaces`).

---

*DISCLAIMER: `route` is considered old fashioned and I ought to be doing this using the `ip route` command; the effect however is identical. Also, adding an `up` statement to `/etc/network/interfaces` may be perceived by some as pre-historic. I'll be happy to upgrade my knowledge.*